# ARREGLADO: Omisión de campos en una tabla al copiarlos usando sql server managenement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, microsoft-sql

estoy haciendo una clonación de datos de una BD en SQL Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio a otra, la primera BD es la BD oficial de la empresa, la cual no debería modificarse, ademas de contar con muchas tablas que no voy a usar. A la hora de hacer la clonación de una tabla en específico (en este caso una llamada Existencias) desde la BD original a la BD que yo voy a usar, me omite unos datos, y no se porque lo hace, incluso llegue a clonar la tabla de la BD original con todas sus columnas e igual me sigue haciendo omision de esos datos, incluyo imagenes para mas referencia

[image: Al seleccionar los primeros top 1000 rows de la tabla Existencia en la BD oficial]

[image: Al seleccionar los primeros top 1000 rows en la tabla Existencia de la BD clonada]

En la primera imagen se ve el resultado de seleccionar los primeros 1000 rows en la tabla Existencia de la BD oficial y en la segunda imagen, lo mismo, pero en la tabla clonada, y aun asi, me omite los campos donde el Id_Almacen es 11A

Lo que hago es seleccionar la tabla original y hacerle esto: un SCRIPT TABLE as: CREATE TO
[image: SCRIPT TABLE de la tabla original]

y el unico campo que cambio es: USE [UNE_2316A_INT] (Base de datos original) a USE [Inventario] (Base de datos nueva).
Incluso dejo intacto las dependencias al final:

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_Existencia] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Id_Producto] ASC,
    [Id_Almacen] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 85) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_Valora_Costo]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [Valora_Costo]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_Criterio_Salida]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [Criterio_Salida]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_Id_Clasificacion]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [Id_Clasificacion]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_Existencia_Inicio1]  DEFAULT ((0.000000)) FOR [Existencia_Actual]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_Importe_InicioMC2]  DEFAULT ((0.00)) FOR [ImporteMB]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_Importe_InicioMC1]  DEFAULT ((0.00)) FOR [ImporteMC]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_Minimo]  DEFAULT ((0.000000)) FOR [Minimo]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_Maximo]  DEFAULT ((0.000000)) FOR [Maximo]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_Lotes]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Lotes]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_Nivel_Pedido]  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [Pto_Reorder]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_Componentes]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Componentes]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_Pto_Seguridad]  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [Pto_Seguridad]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_Venta_Promedio]  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [Venta_Promedio]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_Precio_CostoServicioMB]  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [Precio_CostoServicioMB]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_Precio_CostoServicioMC]  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [Precio_CostoServicioMC]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_ImpuestoMB]  DEFAULT ((0.00)) FOR [ImpuestoMB]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_ABC_PorImporte]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [ABC_PorImporte]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_ABC_PorImporteValor]  DEFAULT ((0.000000)) FOR [ABC_PorImporteValor]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_ABC_PorImporte1]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [ABC_PorConsumoProm]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_ABC_PorImporteValor1]  DEFAULT ((0.000000)) FOR [ABC_PorImpConsumoProm]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_ABC_PorImporte1_1]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [ABC_PorVentaUM]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_ABC_PorImporteValor1_1]  DEFAULT ((0.000000)) FOR [ABC_PorImpVentaUM]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_ABC_PorImporte1_2]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [ABC_PorRota]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_ABC_PorImporteValor1_2]  DEFAULT ((0.000000)) FOR [ABC_PorImpRota]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_ABC_PorImporte1_3]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [ABC_PorImporteCostoVenta]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_ABC_PorImporteValor1_3]  DEFAULT ((0.000000)) FOR [ABC_PorImporteCostoVentaValor]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_ImporteMB1]  DEFAULT ((0.00)) FOR [Empaque]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_Id_ElemGasto]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [Id_ElemGasto]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_Id_SubElemGasto]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [Id_SubElemGasto]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_Id_ElemGastoMC]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [Id_ElemGastoMC]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_Id_SubElemGastoMC]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [Id_SubElemGastoMC]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_Id_Clasificacion1]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [Id_ClasiInicio]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Existencia_Id_Clasiva]  DEFAULT ('S/E') FOR [Id_Clasiva]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_Existencia] CHECK  (([Valora_Costo]>=(1) AND [Valora_Costo]<=(2)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_Existencia]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_Existencia_1] CHECK  (([Criterio_Salida]>=(1) AND [Criterio_Salida]<=(3)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Existencia] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_Existencia_1]
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'1-Ponderado, 2-Por Lotes' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'Existencia', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'Valora_Costo'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'1-PEPS, 2-UEPS, 3-Fecha' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'Existencia', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'Criterio_Salida'
GO
```

Nueva Actualizacion: copie los datos de una BD a la otra e hice un conteo de filas: [image: Conteo de filas de la Tabla original]
[image: Conteo de filas de la Tabla Nueva]
Tienen la misma cantidad de filas.
Al hacer un SELECT TOP 1000 y al final hacerle un ORDER BY Id_Almacen me muestra al fin los campos: [image: Datos seleccionados]

Comment: ¿Qué significa clonar? ¿Como es el proceso que haces para clonar? Te lo comento porque es un poco extraño, lo que dices. ya que si estuviera implementado algo de seguridad  a nivel de fila, no las verías (y se implementó en 2016). Pero que las veas suena raro. Además hasta donde yo conozco Management Studio no tiene Clonar. Tiene copiar de diferentes maneras. La forma más simple de clonar una base de datos, puede ser hacer un backup y un restore con otro nombre.  No será que no las estás viendo ordenadas. Haz una select con un order by. Para asegurarte.

Comment: @Javifer2 me refiero a copiar los datos de la tabla original a otra tabla en otra BD

Comment: Eso me lo supongo. Pero como. Por ejemplo haz  `select * into nuevaTabla from laTabla` Te los va a copiar todos. Después de ejecutarlo, haz un `select Count(*) from laTabla`.  O haz un create table para que tenga todas las mismas columnas y restricciones, y luego haces un insert into NuevaTabla Select * from TablaVieja. Por supuesto se pueden hacer muchas otras cosas.

Comment: @Javifer2 exactamente eso ultimo que comentas fue lo que hice, un Create table con las mismas columnas y restricciones y luego hice un insert into NuevaTabla Select * from TablaVieja. Y aun asi, me omite esos campos

Comment: Estas seguro que te está omitiendo filas? no puede ser simplemente que las consultas no tengan `order by` y obtengas distinto orden? has contado la cantidad de filas en un lugar y en el otro? hay menos filas realmente? Lo único que se me ocurre es que tengas restricciones a nivel fila como ya te comentaron: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @PatricioMoracho estoy segura que me está omitiendo esos datos, porque me tomé la molestia de recorrer todas las filas y esas no aparecían. Conté las filas y sencillamente no aparecen. Aunque si, puede ser una restricción a nivel de fila.

Comment: Row-level security was first introduced to SQL Server 2016 (13.x).

Comment: Porque no editas la pregunta, y pones lo que has hecho explicitamente. Las sentencias, por si hubiera algo en la definición que impida la inserción y tengas algún set que omita por ejemplo las filas truncadas. Con esa configuración, preparamos una sentencia para que tengas todas las filas. ¿Te parece?

Comment: Y has probado usando un linked server y haciendo un select into? te ha dado algún error? algún mensaje? las tablas tienen la misma definición en ambas bases? muchas preguntas, pero es que lo que comentas es algo muy raro.